# Is there a way to manage subdomains with multiple models to be review?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cname

In [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/), Is it possible to configure this? How could I make this happen?

> http://mydomain.com.br (git branch master)
> http://staging1.mydomain.com.br (git branch staging1)
> http://staging2.mydomain.com.br (git branch staging2)

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear but I will try to answer.

You can create the subdomains and point them to CF distribution, S3 bucket (it needs to have the same name as your domain), elastic IP or ALB/ELB domain name.